# Console.log and document.addEventListener is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, xcode, cordova

I'm trying to create a phonegap application in IOS. I had successfully created the project, when running the same application created is being running perfectly, when changing to my code its not detecting any javascript event except alert().

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){}, false);
console.log("I'm working");
```

These functions are not working in Xcode and in iOS device or emulator.

The same application which i created is working fine in android.

Please help me out to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't begin to guess as to why this would work in Android but not iOS. Are you sure you are including  in the head of your html pages? The "deviceready" listiner will not work without it. Everything else looks fine though. The phonegap documentation show the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Device Ready Example</title>

            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Wait for device API libraries to load
            function onLoad() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }

            // device APIs are available
            function onDeviceReady() {
                // Now safe to use device APIs
                ****For testing purposes, add an alert() here to ensure it is working.****
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Dom, I have added above code but not still working. I am using cordova 5.1.1. Do you have any solution?